# How to save button value to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, android-studio, button, sharedpreferences

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Question of the day award!

Answer (score 0):

this is a suggestion.not a question.but i agree on what you said